# Can't post data using mysqli

Tags: php, android, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to insert data into mysql data base, but somewhere something happens and insert doesn't happen.

This is my php skript (init2.php is for connection and I'm 100 proc sure it's successful connection)

```
<?php
require "init2.php";
$model = $_POST["model"];
$total = $_POST["total"];
$dangerous = $_POST["dangerous"];
$unrecognised = $_POST["unrecognised"];

$sql = "insert into AndroidDatabase.ReportTable (MODEL,Total_Packages,Dangerous_Packages,Unrecognised) values ('$model',$total,$dangerous,$unrecognised);";

?>
```

Also this is my code for android :

```
URL url = new URL(REPORT_URL);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream OS =  httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS,"UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("model","UTF-8") + "=" +  URLEncoder.encode(model,"UTF-8") +"&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("total","UTF-8") + "=" +  URLEncoder.encode(total,"UTF-8") +"&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("dangerous","UTF-8") + "=" +  URLEncoder.encode(dangerous,"UTF-8") +"&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("unrecognised","UTF-8") + "=" +  URLEncoder.encode(unrecognised,"UTF-8") ;
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            OS.close();
            InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            IS.close();
```

For mentioning this is "**data**" whish is buffered writen : "model=GT-I9505&total=200&dangerous=0&unrecognised=18"

EDIT:

This worked when I hardcode:

```
<?php
require "init2.php";
$model = "test";
$total = 30;
$dangerous = 30;
$unrecognised = 30;

$sql = "insert into AndroidDatabase.ReportTable (MODEL,Total_Packages,Dangerous_Packages,Unrecognised) values ('$model',$total,$dangerous,$unrecognised)";

if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
echo "success";
}
else
{
echo "error".mysqli_error($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: Where is the php code that tries to insert the sql?

Comment: first code sample

Comment: _first code sample_ No!! there is only one query! This is why I was aksing...

Comment: I think that's why its not inserting into his db haha

Comment: Please check [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: sorry don't really understand what you're asking for. First one is simple php script with insert query. Using Post I pass values for that script which should make insert row into table.

Comment: "_First one is simple php script with insert query_" And that's about it. You'd need to `execute` that query to actually do something

Comment: I was looking at this reference. I don't see any execure commands. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: Also tried just hard codding values and insertion was successful

Answer (score 0):

Tigger link was usefull

```
<?php
require "init2.php";
$model = $_POST["model"];
$total = $_POST["total"];
$dangerous = $_POST["dangerous"];
$unrecognised = $_POST["unrecognised"];
$query = "insert into AndroidDatabase.ReportTable (MODEL,Total_Packages,Dangerous_Packages,Unrecognised) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("siii", $model,$total,$dangerous,$unrecognised);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$con->close();
?>
```